# SQL Server: convert 2 TSQL query results to XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

We have 2 TSQL queries which each return a number from a count statement:

```
select count(*)
from 
    (select 
        *,
        row_number() over (partition by Username order by EntryDatetime desc) as seqnum
    from [log]) t
where 
    seqnum = 1 
    and EventDesc in ('Logon', 'reconnection');

select COUNT(*)
from 
    (select 
        *,
        row_number() over (partition by Username order by EntryDatetime desc) as seqnum
    from [log]
    where EntryDatetime > convert(varchar(255), dateadd(month, -1, getdate()), 121)) t
where 
    seqnum = 1;
```

How can we combine both results to create 1 XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <item>15</item>
    <min>
        <value>0</value>
        <text>Min Users</text>
    </min>
    <max>
       <value>30</value>
       <text>Max Users</text>
    </max>
</root>
```

We have tried using xpshell and bcp but cannot see how 2 query's results can be used to make the same XML file?

Comment: The result doesn't seem related to the XML, so it's impossible to give a specific answer. First create a SELECT statement with the data and names you want, then add the [FOR XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx) clause to generate XML.

Comment: The 1st TSQL statement is for the 15 figure and the 2nd is for the 30 number. The other details in the XML are static.

Comment: Where does `item` and the field names come from? First you need to create a statement that returns the data you want with the names you want. Only then can you convert it to XML.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it all in TSQL with the [FOR XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx) clause, no need to try and combine 2 resultsets externally.

```
; with cte as (
    select 15 as i, 0 as v, 'Min Users' as t
    union all
    select null as i, 30 as v, 'Max Users' as t
)
select
    i as [item],
    v as [min/value], 
    t as [min/text]
from
    cte
for xml path (''), root ('root')
```